# Change the state of parent component on click of a child component with a specific key in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am making a Todo App in React JS, i'm fairly new to React JS.

I have made two components named `AddComponent` and `TodoItem` component. The `AddComponent` has an input and button to add the todos and it will render `TodoItem` as a child component whenever a todo is added using the `AddComponent`.

I also have to remove the child component `TodoItem` when a button inside it is clicked according to it's key, so it would remove that item from the state of the parent component `AddComponent`.

The problem i'm facing is i can't change the state anywhere else than the `render()` function, because there is where i'm dynamically generating the `TodoItem` components using the state.

And changing the state inside the `render()` function would result in an infinite loop. Please help how to resolve this problem.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 using a CDN for styling.

**AddComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import shortid from 'shortid'
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class AddComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            todoText: '',
            todoList: []
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleTodoClick = this.handleTodoClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        e.persist();
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                todoText: e.target.value,
                todoList: prevState.todoList
            }
        })
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                todoText: prevState.todoText,
                todoList: [{
                    text: prevState.todoText,
                    id: shortid.generate()
                }, ...prevState.todoList]
            }
        })
    }
    handleTodoClick(id) {
        const newState = this.state.todoList.filter(todoL => todoL.id === id);
        this.setState({ todoList: newState });
    }

    render() {
        const todos = this.state.todoList.map((todo) => {
            return (
                <TodoItem key={todo.id} value={todo.text} click={this.handleTodoClick(todo.id)}>{todo.text}</TodoItem>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Add a Todo"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                            onClick={this.handleClick}
                        >Add
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {todos}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddComponent
```

**TodoItem.js**

```
import React from 'react'

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    onClick={this.props.click}
                    data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                {this.props.value}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-moon-duqfe

There were two problems; 1st one is filter and the 2nd one is handler callback function that is set to click prop.

1st problem : Filter function should filter that does not match your id so you should use NOT equal :

```js
  handleTodoClick(id) {
    const newState = this.state.todoList.filter(todoL => todoL.id !== id);
    this.setState({ todoList: newState });
  }
```

2nd problem : When you set click prop as a handler callback function, you should set reference of the function itself without calling it. Not like this : `click={this.handleTodoClick(todo.id)`. This will call the function and set the click prop to result of it, which is undefined since it does not return to anything.

So i have changed your click props as `click={this.handleTodoClick}`

```js
    const todos = this.state.todoList.map(todo => {
      return (
        <TodoItem key={todo.id} id={todo.id} value={todo.text} click={this.handleTodoClick}>
          {todo.text}
        </TodoItem>
      );
    });
```

On child component, onClick is similary set to function itself `onClick={() => this.props.click(this.props.id)}` NOT like `onClick={this.props.click(this.props.id)}`.

```js
import React from "react";

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="close"
          onClick={() => this.props.click(this.props.id)}
          data-dismiss="alert"
        >
          &times;
        </button>
        {this.props.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Warning: TodoItem: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. 


This is what i get in the console when i try to delete the first todo added and onclick of the first todo delete button, all todos get deleted.

Comment: i've fixed the filter too. link updated it should work.

Comment: It did work. Thanks. Can you please tell me where was i going wrong and what changes you did? Please make an edit to a post so that the answer could be a little more informative.

Comment: I have explained a bit, let me know the parts you want to ask.

Comment: @MuktadirKhan please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```js
<TodoItem key={todo.id} todoId={todo.id} value={todo.text} click={this.handleTodoClick(todo.id)}>{todo.text}</TodoItem>
```

We can't use `key` as id. The `key` property is used by React under the hood, and is not exposed to us.

```js
import React from 'react'

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    className="close"

                    // look here
                    onClick={e => {this.props.click(this.props.todoId)}}


                    data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                {this.props.value}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoItem
```

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that i'm still changing state inside the `render()` function and that results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by updating the handle for `click` in `AddComponent` then creating a handler within `TodoItem` that calls props `click` with the respective todo item id value. I'd recommend to just pass the entire `todo` so that you can access both the unique `id` and `value` in `TodoItem`:

AddComponent:

```
    const todos = this.state.todoList.map((todo) => {
        return (
            <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} click={this.handleTodoClick}>{todo.text}</TodoItem>
        )
    })
```

TodoItem:

```
import React from 'react'

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.click(this.props.todo.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="close"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {this.props.todo.value}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```